# Will a Smokepowder Satchel explode if I'm lit on fire while carrying it?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

I picked up a Smokepowder Satchel that says it explodes when ignited, damaging everything in the vicinity. Some enemy spells can inflict burning. Will a Smokepowder Satchel explode if a character gets lit on fire while carrying it in their inventory?

[image: Smokepowder Satchel description]

Comment: RAW for most D&D 5E spells that can cause things to catch on fire also explicitly exclude items a creature is wearing or carrying.  I would expect BG3 to respect that as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nope.

Your inventory is safe from the environment, and vice versa.

That said, a lit grenade is *probably* not the best thing to store in your pack, even if you're the only one who's going to suffer for it. But even in such a case, the rest of your items (smokepowder satchels included) are fine.

Comment: "I wish I had a Bag of Holding". Well, you have a Bag of Inertia, which is a bloody good start :)